# Кнопка ведет себя очень странно

Tags: android, android-button

Возникла такая проблема: есть код кнопки:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_out"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_out"
            android:text="@string/exit"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progres_bar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        </Button>
```

Код background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/btn_sign_out"/>
    <corners android:radius="26dp"/>
</shape>
```

После запуска должна была получиться розовая кнопка с текстом который идеально подходит. Так она собственно и выглядит на пререндере android studio, но при запуске на эмуляторе\устройстве выходит это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего у вас стоит `MaterialTheme` и вместо `Button` инфлейтится `MaterialButton` из библиотеки `com.google.android.material:material`, в которой background атрибут работает не так как ожидается https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673053/cant-use-androidbackground-with-button-from-the-new-material-components

Замените `android:background="@drawable/sign_out"` на

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/btn_sign_out"
app:cornerRadius="26dp"
```

Атрибуты [`MaterialButton`](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button).